# When to use LocationManager/LocationListener VS. LocationServices/LocationCallback to track user location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

I've implemented user geolocation tracking with the following:

### #1

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mMap.clear();
            repaintUserLocationPin(location);
        }
```

### #2

```
locationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
        if (locationList.size() > 0) {
            //The last location in the list is the newest
            Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);

            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            repaintUserLocationPin(mLastLocation);
        }
    }
};
```

To summarize IMHO:

- These both seem to achieve the same,track and update the current user's location.
- At the end of the day, they are both equally verbose and have the same complexity.
- #2 needs new 'implementation' libraries but, this isn't much of an overhead

On the other hand, there is a **3rd** solution but this doesn't allow me to get the updated current location **unless**, I click on the *Geolocate button* in the map. I'm talking about:

```
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GeolocateBtnClickListener(MapsActivity.this));
    map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(new GeolocateClickListener(MapsActivity.this));
```

This has one BIG advantage, and it's that the marker is automatically created and it is much more responsive to the user's movements. For example, it points in the directo that the user is pointing at.

So, Why use one over the other or in what cases would you recommend using one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

All the below is just my opinions

> These both seem to achieve the same,track and update the current
>   user's location.

The difference can be realized with their location obtain ways. `LocationManager` gives us chance of choosing the location source. So then we can pick any source from gps, network and passive alternatives. But `LocationServices` does not give this chance, instead gives taste of location, the momentum of between quality and battery usage.

> At the end of the day, they are both equally verbose and have the same
>   complexity.

Configuring them seems a bit same, but `LocationServices` could be first option. Deciding quality/power seems more reasonable than dealing with providers.

> #2 needs new 'implementation' libraries but, this isn't much of an overhead

`LocationManager` is available from version 1, while `LocationServices` is available if device supports play services.